# CKEditor 4/5 detect true user initiated on change event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I have a bunch of code that represents a complex behaviour in ckeditor, anyway the code in question does this.

```
onNewDataAvailable(newData){
  this.cancelChangeTrigger = true;
  CKEDITOR.instances[this.name].setData(newData);
}

onSetup(){
  CKEDITOR.replace(this.name, this.config);
  CKEDITOR.instances[this.name].on('change', ()=>{
    if (this.cancelChangeTrigger){
      return;
    }

    let data = CKEDITOR.instances[this.name].getData();
    if (data !== this.currentData){
      this.dataHasUpdated(data);
    }
  });
  CKEDITOR.instances[this.name].on('key', ()=>{
    this.cancelChangeTrigger = false;
  })
}
```

Now the reason there is this cancelChange trigger was because every time that I called `setData` as new data is available I get an change event triggered just as ckeditor just wants to format things, even when the actual content hasn't changed; the cancelChangeTrigger allows me to cancel triggering a change event on my server side without the content actually changing.

So the `cancelChangeTrigger` was added, however it is more like a hack, and the problem now is that if the user has an image, `cancelChangeTrigger` remains false, and no change event is registered.

Is there a less hacky way to detect true change events?... for ckeditor 4 and 5, there will be a migration eventually.